# Default routing in react-router-dom not working, when using conditional rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have the following React component:

```
function Routes(props) {
  const { role, userId } = props;

  const renderMemberTasksPage = (props) => {
    //Redirects to 404 or not
  };

  const renderTracksPage = (props) => {
     //Redirects to 404 or not
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/members/:id/tasks' render={renderMemberTasksPage} />
        <Route exact path='/members/:id/tasks/id:open?' render={renderMemberTasksPage} />

        {role === 'admin' && (
          <Route path='/members/new'>
            <NewMember />
          </Route>
        )}

        {(role === 'admin' || role === 'mentor') && (
          <>
            <Route exact path='/'>
              <Redirect to='/members' />
            </Route>
            <Route exact path='/members'>
              <MembersManagerPage />
            </Route>
            <Route exact path='/tasks/'>
              <MemberTasksPage />
            </Route>
            <Route path='/tasks/new'>
              <NewTask />
            </Route>
            <Route exact path='/tasks/id:open?'>
              <MemberTasksPage />
            </Route>
            <Route path='/tasks/id:open/edit'>
              <MemberTasksPage edit />
            </Route>
            <Route path='/members/:id/progress'>
              <MemberProgressPage />
            </Route>
          </>
        )}

        {role === 'member' && (
          <>
            <Route exact path='/'>
              <Redirect to={`/members/${userId}/tasks`} />
            </Route>
            <Route path='/members/:id/tracks' render={renderTracksPage} />
          </>
        )}

        <Route exact path='/404'>
          <Error404Page />
        </Route>

        <Route path='*'>
          <Redirect to='/404' />
        </Route>

      </Switch>
    </>
  );
}
```

In simple words, this code defines routes depending on the current user role. Here I've got a problem: default router `*` is not working. Different order of routes and using `exact` in different combinations showed no results. When I removed all routes, rendered conditionally, it worked. Can it be the reason and how to avoid such behavior?

My version of react-router-dom:

```
 "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2"
```

Comment: Try changing `<Route path='*'><Redirect to='/404' /></Route>` to `<Route path='*'><Error404Page /></Route>`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can remove the path='*' and put directly the component inside the `<Route>`

It would be something like that:

```
   <Route>
      <Error404Page />
   </Route>
```

since the Switch will try to match every path the last one will be used if it can't find any

Comment: Good idea, but didn't help(

Comment: It seems to work this way. Here is an exemple froma ntoher thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/56687011/9868549. also, the accepted answer demonstrate the use of a redirection to always fallback on the homepage, that can be a solution as well