# catch 404 pages with nested routes in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I would like to catch 404 pages when user enter un Uri not defined in the app.

I have a `Home` route `/` . inside it I have children routes.
Then I have other routes in top level ( same level as `Home`.

My problem is with the children routes `/children1` `/children2`

When I type `/strangeRoute`react loads the content of `/` then the 404 page.

That's because I'm not applying `exact` in `Home` route. And I should not add it because I should show `Home` content + `Children1/Children2` content , not one or  children routes.

The unique solution that I see is to store all routes then every page request (Using protected route ) check if the taped route correspond to an existing one, if not redirect it to 404 page.

Is there a simpler way to do it ?

```
import React from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route, // for later
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";

const topics = [
  {
    name: "React Router",
    id: "react-router",
  },
  {
    name: "React.js",
    id: "reactjs",
  },
  {
    name: "Functional Programming",
    id: "functional-programming",
  }
];

function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Topics</h1>
      <ul>
        {topics.map(({ name, id }) => (
          <li key={id}>
            <Link to={`/${id}`}>{name}</Link>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>

      <hr />
      <Route exact path={`/react-router`} component={Topic} />
      <Route exact path={`/reactjs`} component={Topic} />
      <Route exact path={`/functional-programming`} component={Topic} />
    </div>
  );
}

function Topic() {
  return <div>TOPIC</div>;
}

function NotFound() {
  return <div>Page 404</div>;
}

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Route path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route component={NotFound} />
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I couldn't make a snipped here so here's a codesandbox [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/nested-routes-4-forked-umbg0?file=/src/App.js:0-2863)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56684856/how-to-define-fallback-route-properly-in-react-router-dom

Comment: It's not the same case as mine, I tried it but not able to make my example works

Comment: is there any different if you put `<Route path="*" component={NotFound} />`?

Comment: It will always show the links list + 404 message , What I want is to only show 404 message when strange url is entered ( the links list should not be shown )

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this Solution using redirects:

https://codesandbox.io/s/nested-routes-4-forked-scebd?file=/src/App.js